# Solving the equation for $a$: $\lim_{x\to2}\frac{\sin(x^2+ax)}{x^2+ax+x}=\frac{2}{3}$

Tags: limits

I need some help to solve the following equation:
$$\lim_{x\to2}\frac{\sin(x^2+ax)}{x^2+ax+x}=\frac{2}{3}$$

I believe that I have to get to $$\frac{a}{a+1}=\frac{2}{3}$$ but I don't know exactly how to do it. If there is a rule/theorem that I can apply, please explain.

Comment: You would get to $a/(a+1)$ if the limit were about $x\to0$. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Taylor expansion around $x=2$
$$\sin(x^2+ax)=\sin (2 a+4)+(x-2) (a \cos (2 a+4)+4 \cos (2 a+4))+O\left((x-2)^2\right)$$
$$x^2+ax+x=(2 a+6)+(a+5) (x-2)+O\left((x-2)^2\right)$$ Now, long division to get
$$\frac{\sin(x^2+ax)}{x^2+ax+x}=\frac{\sin (2 a+4)}{2 a+6}+O\left((x-2)\right)$$

If you plot the function, you will see that the root is "close" to $-\pi$. Make a series expansion
$$\frac{\sin (2 a+4)}{2 a+6}=\frac{\sin (4)}{6-2 \pi }+(a+\pi ) \left(\frac{2 \cos (4)}{6-2 \pi }-\frac{2 \sin
   (4)}{(6-2 \pi )^2}\right)+O\left((a+\pi )^2\right)$$ and this will give as an *approximation* 
$$a=-\pi-\frac{(\pi -3) (4 \pi +3 (\sin (4)-4))}{3 \sin (4)+6 (\pi -3) \cos (4)}\approx -3.22698$$ while the exact solution, obtained by Newton method, would be $a\approx  -3.33745\sim -\frac{10}3$.

Answer (score 1):

We can easily see that for $x^2+ax\to 0$ (or $k\pi$) the limit would be zero then, in order to have a finite limit, the expression needs to be continuous at $x=a$ and we obtain

$$\frac{\sin(4+2a)}{6+2a}=\frac{2}{3}$$

which has a solution at $a \approx -\frac{10}3$.